# Missing Folder from Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have to debug a javascript file and for that I opened my chrome developer tool(please see the image below). I was expecting a folder named `builders` inside `scripts` folder which contains the javascript files I need to debug but it's not there. I updated the chrome to the latest version 53.0.2785.116 m (64 bit) but no luck.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried searching for the file you want directly using `Ctrl+P`? Also, what _is_ in the builders directory? Because the name suggests it may be the build tools which I wouldn't expect to see on a webpage.

Comment: This could be due to no files being included, can you check the importing URL?

Comment: @vlaz Where would you like me to do `Ctrl+P` ? In the developer tool? `builders` folders contains some javascript files which are basically used to build the webpage. Basically they are getting data via ajax call and displaying on webpage.

Comment: @Roberrrt Could you please elaborate on `importing URL` ? Thanks

Comment: Basically what all the answer-givers were saying, but if you state your app wouldn't be working without it, I suppose that is not the problem.

Comment: @John - `Ctrl + P` in the Sources tab in the dev tools, yes. Also, if the build tools are what is _building_ your page, then, by definition, they won't be included _on_ the page. They would be invoked before the page gets displayed at all.

Comment: @vlaz Thanks. `Ctrl + P` in the sources tab couldn't locate the file I am trying to debug. If by definition, build tools won't be included on the page, then how can I debug if I have to?

Comment: @John well, not easily. There is a way to attach a remote debugger to a JS file, I believe, but I've personally not actually done it. I suggest using generous amount of `console.log` statements that will tell you what the build tools are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the script is included in the the home.html file

`<script src="scripts/builders/SCRIPTNAME.js"></script>`

Comment: It's there, because if it wasn't there, my web app won't be working.

Comment: Of course. According to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862344/chrome-developer-tools-do-not-show-all-javascript-files-any-more, it looks like it may be a bug in Chrome. A number of solutions are offered there

Comment: If it's a bug, looks like google still hasn't fixed it. The author in the above post is using `Version 44.0.2403.130 ` and it's `version 53.0.2785.116` that I am using. Strange !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just forgot to link a script file from scripts/builders/ directory. Try to filter scripts files in `Network` tab.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the case. My webapp is working fine. The only problem is that the file isn't traceable on the developer tool.